# Enabling the search engines to index data from web application

Tags: java, database, web-applications, search, search-engine

I am building a social web application using Java and Cassandra DB. I want some of the data from my database to be visible to search engines. 
Since my application is completely dynamic & contains data only in DB and not in static pages, how do the crawlers read this data?

*1.)How can I ensure that the data stored on my servers can be seen by the search engines? My application contains user specific data*

*2.)How do the search engines access that data ??*

*3.)How can I limit the search engines crawling only to some specific data?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to separate user specific info from public info, either you should have public and private pages - or you could decorate you'r public page with user specifics through some session based Ajax calls.

Meaning: the browser just load the public version of the page, while a javascript would load the users specifics and inject them into the page.

2 and 3 could be solved by uploading a site map to Google.

Or do you want Google to talk to Cassendra directly...? Then ignore all above - I think.

Comment: "Or do you wan't Google to talk to Cassendra directly...? Then ignore all above."  Would this be a good thing to do ?

Comment: And wrt to your first point, do the crawlers read the data only when it is displayed to users on the frontend? is there no mechanism by which they can be allowed to safely access the data just from the backend

Comment: You should consider crawlers users wich does not support cookies or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Read [the explanations from Google](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182072).

The search engines access your data as any other user of your website : by browsing it and clicking all the links they find. Content accessible only through AJAX will be more difficult to make accessible by search engines.

Access can be restricted using a robots.txt file. Explanations are given in the link given above.

Comment: but what if my application allows authenticated sessions only?? How will the data be accessible to the engines

Comment: I fixed the link. If your website is private, then the search engines won't be able to access it. But why would it be useful : all the search results they would display would be inaccessible anyway.